# Can't upload data from DataTable to Database in WPF .NET 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dataset

I am writing an app WPF C# .NET 5.0 that converts numbers from metric to imperial (and vice-versa). I am having a weird issue with data not uploading to the database. I successfully downloaded data from the database, but I cannot display it in my data grid.

The database is connected via DataSetProj.xsd file.
Here's how my database looks like:
[image: img]

My app has 3 tabs, one for converter, one for datagrid, and one for other stuff. Whenever input in converter changes, it automatically converts, and adds a record to `Stats` table.

My app properly reads data from `Converters`, `MetricUnits` and `ImperialUnits` tables (not sure about `Stats`, because this table is empty).

**FYI** those are my fields I use to communicate with DB:

```
        DataSetProj DBProj = new DataSetProj();
        DataSetProjTableAdapters.ConvertersTableAdapter convertersTableAdapter = new();
        DataSetProjTableAdapters.StatsTableAdapter statsTableAdapter = new();
        DataSetProjTableAdapters.ImperialUnitsTableAdapter imperialUnitsTableAdapter = new();
        DataSetProjTableAdapters.MetricUnitsTableAdapter metricUnitsTableAdapter = new();
        DataSetProjTableAdapters.StatsViewTableAdapter statsViewTableAdapter = new();
```

Here's the launch-time code:

```
    convertersTableAdapter.Fill(DBProj.Converters);
    statsTableAdapter.Fill(DBProj.Stats);
    imperialUnitsTableAdapter.Fill(DBProj.ImperialUnits);
    metricUnitsTableAdapter.Fill(DBProj.MetricUnits);
```

When I want to add a record to my database, this code invokes:

```
private void addStat(double input, double output)
        {
            DataSetProj.ConvertersRow usedConverter = DBProj.Converters.Where(x => x.NameOf == (ConvertersList.SelectedItem as IConverter).ToString()).First();
            DataSetProj.MetricUnitsRow metricUnit;
            // this if statement exists, because ConvertLength has multiple metric units, like kilometre, metre, etc.
            if (ConvertersList.SelectedItem is ConvertLength)
            {
                metricUnit = DBProj.MetricUnits.Where(x => x.NameOf == BoxUnitChoice.SelectedItem.ToString()).First();
            }
            else
            {
                metricUnit = DBProj.MetricUnits.Where(x => x.NameOf == (ConvertersList.SelectedItem as IConverter).MetricUnit(true)).First();
            }
            DataSetProj.ImperialUnitsRow imperialUnit = DBProj.ImperialUnits.Where(x => x.NameOf == (ConvertersList.SelectedItem as IConverter).ImperialUnit(true)).First();
            DBProj.Stats.AddStatsRow(DBProj.Stats.Count, DateTime.Now, (metricToImperial ? 1 : 0), metricUnit, imperialUnit, usedConverter, input, output);
        }
```

And it works - DBProj.Stats.Count increases every time a record is added. However, when I switch to the tab with the data grid (`TabStats`), it does not show any stats at all. It uses `StatsView` as a source, not `Stats` directly (or at least that's how I want it to work).

This code invokes when I switch to `TabStats`:

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Tabs.SelectedItem as TabItem) == TabStats)
            {
                DBProj.Stats.AcceptChanges();
                statsViewTableAdapter.Fill(DBProj.StatsView);
                //neither of these 2 lines populate my datagrid
                StatsDataGrid.ItemsSource = DBProj.StatsView;
                //StatsDataGrid.ItemsSource = statsViewTableAdapter.GetData();
                MessageBox.Show($"{DBProj.Stats.Count} this is stat count\n{DBProj.StatsView.Count} and this is statsView", "test");
            }
        }
```

Here's the output of the message box after I input a couple of values (note data grid is empty):
[image: msgbox]

To my knowledge, it looks like the data is stored locally in DBProj.Stats table, but is not sent back to my database (where `StatsView` attempts to get data from). However, isn't `.AcceptChanges()` supposed to send any changes I made?

How do I send data back to the database using WPF .NET 5.0? All tutorials I found either used EF or only ever referenced `.AcceptChanges()` method.

EDIT: I forgot to add, but the data is never saved in the database - every time I run the program, `Stats` is empty. I want it to save when I switch to `TabStats` tab, as stated above.

Comment: You need .update() rather than acceptchanges.  I recommend using an orm like entity framework or a micro orm like dapper instead of strongly typed datasets.

Comment: @Andy problem is, there is no `.update()` method. Entity framework is for .NET 4.8 Framework, not .NET 5.0, hence my question - is there any way to make it work on .NET 5.0? Surely databases must work on this standard somehow!

Comment: @Andy I was looking for the `.update()` method in the data table, not the database :) one quick fix and the code is working, thank you so much for inspiring me to find a working solution!

Comment: Ef core is now a nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to inspiration from @Andy, I managed to solve the issue. Instead of using `.AcceptChanges()` on the Data table, I had to `.Update()` Data table adapter - I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/update-data-by-using-a-tableadapter?view=vs-2019) doc, which explains how to add data to an existing data table using SQL `INSERT` command. Here's the working code:

```
    private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Tabs.SelectedItem as TabItem) == TabStats)
        {
            //DBProj.Stats.AcceptChanges();
            statsTableAdapter.Update(DBProj.Stats);
            statsViewTableAdapter.Fill(DBProj.StatsView);
            StatsDataGrid.ItemsSource = DBProj.StatsView;
            //StatsDataGrid.ItemsSource = statsViewTableAdapter.GetData();
            MessageBox.Show($"{DBProj.Stats.Count} this is stat count\n{DBProj.StatsView.Count} and this is statsView", "test");
        }
    }
```